# How to recalculate tax on new row total in magento?

Tags: magento

I’m making a call to `$item->calcRowTotal()` on a `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item` object.

This works great to reset the `row total` and `base row total`, but it does not affect the row total including tax (`row_total_incl_tax`) attribute on the item.

I assume I have to manually do this after I have the new row total but I can’t figure out how to *properly* calculate the tax and populate the `row_total_incl_tax` attribute on the item.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Get the tax rate and recalculate `row_total_incl_tax`. Here's how you can get tax rate.

Assuming your order no. is 101.

```
$sale = Mage::getModel('sales/sale)->load(101)
$taxModel = Mage::getModel('sales/order_tax')
        ->load($sale->getId(), 'order_id');
$taxRate = $taxModel->getPercent()
```

I think you know how to calculate the tax amount based on `row total` value.

**Edit**:

Get tax based on product:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item-getProductId());
$request = Mage::getSingleton('tax/calculation')
                    ->getRateRequest()
                    ->setProductClassId($product->getTaxClassId());

$taxRate = Mage::getSingleton('tax/calculation')
                ->getRate($request);
```

So you know the tax rate, `row_total_incl_tax` is sum of tax * qty + total amount (or you can calculate anyway you want). May be you need to check if item price is included tax or not, you can do this by `Mage::getModel('Tax/Config')->priceIncludesTax()`

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion but i need to recalculate the tax before placing the order.

Comment: In that case you need to get tax based on product, Let me edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks but where can i do these calculation in my custom module so they won't be rewrite by magento core. I mean using which event I can reset this tax amounts.

Comment: Write in same file, after the line `$item->calcRowTotal()`

Comment: Actually I was trying to rewrite the calcRowTotal() method in my custom module in which i was updating the row total with extra amount.  But when prices are incl tax in cart the rowtotal does not added up my extra amount. Any idea where should i recalculate the tax on my new row total?